# Split string to array and loop through it MYSQL

Tags: mysql, procedure

Consider a string `A=1,B=2,...`. Need to loop through it and insert it in table using MySQL procedure such as:

```
Name |Value
----------
A    | 1

B    | 2
```

How can it be done?

Comment: if your strings store in a file, you could replace  `,`  to "\n" with program language, then load the file into table with "=" as column delemeter. if your strings store in table , export to file.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a stored procedure which takes a string parameter as an argument then inside the stored procedure you can split that string in to separated values using mysql string functions and insert into the table